# how to scale a gif in tkinter canvas

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to scale the size of the image while zooming in and out.
Here is the function I am using and trying to resize the gif. I know the code is wrong but I just wanted to show what I was trying.

```
def zoomin(self, event):
    font_size = 15
    font_size1 = 5
    Width = 10
    Width1 = 50
    d = event.delta
    if d < 0:
       amt=0.9
    else:
       amt=1.1
    self.canvas.scale(ALL,200, 200, amt, amt)

    font_size *= amt
    Width *= amt
    Width1 *= amt
    height1 *= amt

    self.gif1 = Image.open("Apple.gif") #Image Path
    self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.line, width= float(Width))
    self.gif1 = self.gif1.resize((Width1, height1), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photoImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.gif1)

    self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.text, font= (FONT_NAME, int(font_size))

def zoom out(self,event):
    font_size = 15
    font_size1 = 5
    Width = 10

    d = event.delta
    if d > 0:
       amt=1.1
    else:
       amt=0.7
    self.canvas.scale(ALL,200, 200, amt, amt)
    font_size *= amt
    Width *= amt
    Width1 *= amt
    height1 *= amt
    actual_width = Width-1
    self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.line, width= float(actual_width))
```

I have not tried anything for zoom out as I am unable to resize the gif while zooming in. I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: What does this code do, what do you want it to do, and how are those two things different?

Comment: Hello, sorry for not putting in the values. The above code is regarding the scaling of fonts and texts while zoom in/out functionality(using Mousewheel). I have achieved that but I am not able to scale the gifs(getting bigger while zooming in and getting smaller when zooming out).

Comment: What does "not able to" mean? Why aren't you able to? Does the code throw an error? If so, what error? If not, what does it do differently than you expect? Does it do nothing? Does it make the image smaller instead of larger? Larger instead of smaller? Something else?

Comment: I am not getting any error but I am not getting the output which I am expecting. To make the question simple, when I zoom in/out(using "Mousewheel") I want the gif buttons to be resized accordingly.